# Nested route is showing white blank screen in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a URL like `/user/info`, but when I hit the URL, it shows a white blank screen. I have tried to resolve this issue, but unfortunately, I am not able to do so. I will attach my code as well to show what I have tried. Any support would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Routes**

```
import React from "react";
import { AppLayout } from "ui";
import { AppRoute } from "types";
import Dashboard from "pages/dashboard/index";
import InfoScreen from "pages/vendor/dashboard";

const routes: AppRoute[] = [
  {
    path: "/user",
    component: Dashboard,
    exact: true,
    layout: AppLayout,
    indexRoute: true,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/info",
        component: InfoScreen,
        exact: false,
        layout: AppLayout,
        indexRoute: false,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default routes;
```

**Render Component** ||
Wrapper Component:

```
const Wrapper: React.FC = () => {
  return <Outlet />;
};

<StylesProvider>
        <Router>
          <div className="app bg-body">
            <OktaProvider>
              <AuthProvider>
                <Provider store={store}>
                  <Routes>
                    {routes.map((route, index) => {
                      return (
                        <Route
                          key={index}
                          path={route.path}
                          element={
                            route.layout ? (
                              <route.layout appName="Envio" />
                            ) : (
                              <Wrapper />
                            )
                          }
                        >
                          <Route
                            key={index}
                            path={route.path}
                            index={route.indexRoute ? true : undefined}
                            element={<route.component />}
                          />
                          {route.children?.map((child, index) => (
                            <Route
                              key={index}
                              path={child.path}
                              index={route.indexRoute ? true : undefined}
                              element={<child.component />}
                            />
                          ))}
                        </Route>
                      );
                    })}
    
                  </Routes>
                </Provider>
              </AuthProvider>
            </OktaProvider>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </StylesProvider>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the `Wrapper` component and the other components used as layouts, e.g. `AppLayout`, so we can see what they render? I suspect they are missing an `Outlet` for the nested routes. Please include any other code you feel may be relevant here. See [mcve].

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, Added wrapper component. Could you please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Looks like `Wrapper` renders an `Outlet`, but what about `AppLayout`? If `AppLayout` also renders an `Outlet` then do you think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese `AppLayout` is not running `Outlet`. `AppLayout` is separate component for the menu

Comment: I see, so it's not intended to be a layout rout component? It's just some extra UI that is conditionally rendered?

Comment: Yes, That's correct. When I hit a url like `/user` it working fine but when I add `/user/info` it showing empty white screen

Answer (score 0):

In order for nested routes to output and render their `element` content, their parent route component ***must*** render an `Outlet`. The `Wrapper` component does so.

```
const Wrapper: React.FC = () => {
  return <Outlet />;
};
```

But if `AppLayout` is not rendering an `Outlet` and is only intended to be a separate component for the menu, then `AppLayout` cannot be used as a layout route component. Refactor the UI code to ***conditionally*** render `route.layout` when it is provide and ***unconditionally*** render the `Wrapper` component for the nested routes.

Example:

```
<StylesProvider>
  <Router>
    <div className="app bg-body">
      <OktaProvider>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Routes>
              {routes.map((route, index) => {
                return (
                  <Route
                    key={index}
                    path={route.path}
                    element={(
                      <>
                        {route.layout && <route.layout appName="Envio" />}
                        <Wrapper />
                      </>
                    )}
                  >
                    <Route
                      {...route.indexRoute
                        ? { index: true }
                        : { path: route.path }
                      }
                      element={<route.component />}
                    />
                    {route.children?.map((child, index) => (
                      <Route
                        key={index}
                        {...child.indexRoute
                          ? { index: true }
                          : { path: child.path }
                        }
                        element={<child.component />}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </Route>
                );
              })}
            </Routes>
          </Provider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </OktaProvider>
    </div>
  </Router>
</StylesProvider>
```

You are kind of reinventing the wheel here though when it comes to rendering the routes. You could rewrite the `routes` code to align with what React-Router-DOM uses natively.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import type { RouteObject } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppLayout } from "ui";
import Dashboard from "pages/dashboard/index";
import InfoScreen from "pages/vendor/dashboard";

const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: "/user",
    element: (
      <>
        <AppLayout />
        <Outlet />
      </>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Dashboard />
      },
      {
        path: "info",
        element: <InfoScreen />,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default routes;
```

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from '../path/to/routes';

const App = () => {
  const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);

  return (
    <StylesProvider>
      <div className="app bg-body">
        <OktaProvider>
          <AuthProvider>
            <Provider store={store}>
              {appRoutes}
            </Provider>
          </AuthProvider>
        </OktaProvider>
      </div>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
};
```

```
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

Comment: Hi Drew, Thank you for the answer but I am getting this error in the routes file 

'Dashboard' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Dashboard'?ts(2749)

Comment: @Suhas Sorry, I assumed that `Dashboard` was a React component. Is it a component or is it a type declaration? Which implementation do you have this error with?

Comment: No, Dashboard and InfoScreen is a component

Comment: @Suhas Thank you. Which suggested code implementation in my answer is causing  the issue? If it helps, maybe you could try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of the code you are using that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?